# NSFetchRequest with NSPredicate sometimes throws NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

This one is baffling me:

I have a core data set that I search/filter using the following code:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Lead" inManagedObjectContext:moc]];
NSString *predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"("
                       "(isLocalVersion == %@) AND (LeadStatusID =='Active')"
                       ") AND ("
                       "(LeadID contains[cd] '%@')"
                       "OR (AccountNumber contains[cd] '%@')"
                       "OR (ANY contactItems.FirstName contains[cd] '%@')"
                       "OR (ANY contactItems.LastName contains[cd] '%@')"
                       "OR (ANY addressItems.Address1 contains[cd] '%@')"
                       "OR (ANY addressItems.City contains[cd] '%@')"
                       ")", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], sTerm, sTerm, sTerm, sTerm, sTerm, sTerm];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *leads = nil;
@try {
    leads = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    LogSevere(@"Error Executing Fetch Request: %@", exception);
    leads = [NSArray array];
}
@finally {
    [fetchRequest release];
}
```

sTerm is just a `NSString`.

This works 95% of the time, however every once in a while it catches an `NSInvalidArgumentException: Can't use in/contains operator with collection 10076173 (not a collection).`

The Predicate String formats to be this:

> ((isLocalVersion == 1) AND
>   (LeadStatusID =='Active')) AND
>   ((LeadID contains[cd] 'i')OR
>   (AccountNumber contains[cd] 'i')OR
>   (ANY contactItems.FirstName
>   contains[cd] 'i')OR (ANY
>   contactItems.LastName contains[cd]
>   'i')OR (ANY addressItems.Address1
>   contains[cd] 'i')OR (ANY
>   addressItems.City contains[cd] 'i'))

My catch allows me to not crash and just return 0 results, but this isn't optimal.  Has anyone ever seen this before?

My only clue is that it **seems** to happen after I modify (and save) a record in the core data (again only sometimes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you can't have expressions that evaluate to collections as part of a fetchRequest's predicate.  [This is in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsexpression#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001190-SW8):

> Aggregate expressions are not supported by Core Data.

Comment: Ok, so in that case I should get the result set for `isLocalVersion` and `LeadStatusID` and then evaluate each of the remaining expressions individually and combine the results?

Comment: Thanks. Executing the ORs separately and combining the results seems to be working.

Comment: But I don't see any aggregate expressions here. Can you point out which parts are aggregate expressions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> The Core Data SQL store supports only one to-many operation per query; therefore in any predicate sent to the SQL store, there may be only one operator (and one instance of that operator) from `ALL`, `ANY`, and `IN`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html

What might be happening is:

- if one of the early conditions evaluates to `TRUE`, the remaining conditions are not evaluated, so no crash occurs
- if you get to `OR (ANY contactItems.FirstName contains[cd] '%@')` and it's `TRUE`, you get your first use of `ANY`, no crash occurs
- if you get to `OR (ANY contactItems.LastName contains[cd] '%@')`, you get your second use of `ANY`, **crash occurs**

You need to execute the ANYs separately and combine the results, possibly using [NSCompoundPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscompoundpredicate);

Answer (score 1):

Is **LeadID** a int property by any chance? I just ran into this same problem, constructing a predicate where I check to see if one or more properties contain a search term. It worked *most* of the time, but every now and then it would fail with an error just like yours.

The problem was that all of the properties I was checking were strings except one. When I removed that property from the predicate, everything worked fine.

I suspect **10076173** is the int value of LeadID for some object in your database. It appears that Core Data will *usually* convert the int to string like you expect, but sometimes it doesn't and that's when the error happens. The **CONTAINS** operator doesn't make sense on an integer and it crashes.

---

As further evidence, I tried changing the predicate to use **LIKE** instead of **CONTAINS** and I got a related error which finally tipped me off to what was happening. The predicate was

> itemNumber LIKE "*test*" OR model LIKE "*test*" OR productDescription LIKE "*test*" [..snip..]

and the exception was

> 'Can't do regex matching on object 1008.'

At the point I realized 1008 looked familiar... like an itemNumber, which is an Int32.

---

As for the reason Core Data usually, but not always, converts an int property to a string when you use the CONTAINS operator, I don't know. But I do know that the predicate worked fine until the context had unsaved changes: specifically when an object's to-many relationship property was changed.

Comment: Wow, very helpful info.  I'll have to investigate this further.  I used a cludge to work around the problem, but may re-investigate it with this info. +1

Answer (score 1):

Found a similar problem with a predicate that was checking for NSDecimalNumber longitude and part of it came to `longitude<-23` and caused an `obj_c_exception_throw` with no more details. The fix was to ensure that there was a space after the `<`, i.e. `longitude < -23`. It basically crashed for anything with `<-` together, but not `>-`.

NSPredicate throws some odd undocumented errors.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remember having a similar problem with collections in Core Data, where my fetch predicate somehow resulted in invalid SQL (other data store types worked fine). It's not an ideal solution, but if you have few enough objects you could do a complete fetch and then filter the result set after the fact.